# Creating Bitmap image from OpenGL ES Framebuffer through JNI on Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to capture the frame buffer data from OpenGL ES and create an image from it, basically as a way to capture a screen-shot

I am trying to use the BitmapFactory class through JNI to do the conversion. Here is my current code:

```cpp
size_t size = w * h;
uint8_t *pixels = new uint8_t[size];
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
jobject jbitmap = 0;

if(pixels != 0) {
  JNIEnv * env = GetEnv(state_->activity->vm);

  //create the jbyte array and fill in with the pixel data
  int byte_array_length = w * h;
  jbyteArray byte_array = env->NewByteArray(byte_array_length);
  env->SetByteArrayRegion(byte_array, 0, byte_array_length, (jbyte *)pixels);

  //get the BitmapFactory class
  jclass bitmap_factory_class = loadExternalClass("android/graphics/BitmapFactory");
  jmethodID decode_byte_array_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(bitmap_factory_class,
    "decodeByteArray", "([BII)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");

  //get the bitmap itself
  jbitmap = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(bitmap_factory_class, decode_byte_array_method,
    byte_array, 0, byte_array_length);

  env->DeleteLocalRef(byte_array);
}

if(jbitmap == 0) {
  Log("Could not create image from framebuffer to share");
}
```

Basically, what the code is trying to do is:

- Capture opengl framebuffer into pixels array
- Create jbyteArray of size W*H
- Populate jbytearray
- Get BitmapFactory class
- Call decodeByteArray method with the jbytearray

However, the jbitmap object is continuously set to 0, which makes me think that the BitmapFactory call fails and I have no idea why

The same code used for capturing the frame buffer into the pixels array (ie: the glReadPixels call) is used without problem on iOS & MacOSX, so I do not think that the problem lies there

So, any help on what I may be missing?

Comment: Originally posted to the [android-ndk google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/oA6v40n49S8)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I have logged all three (w, h & pixels). W & H indeed match my screen size and pixels is non-null and not full of zeros either. It is a bit difficult for me to figure out if it is indeed valid data in there or not, but I'm guessing it should be, since its just a straight glReadPixels call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you calling *decode* on the data returned by `glReadPixels (...)`? The data is raw RGB[A] in most cases; it would make more sense to ***encode*** it. This could be correct for all I know, but that is one hell of a stupid thing for Google to call a function that encodes a raw buffer of pixels into a more specialized collection of pixels.

I have to imagine from an intuitive perspective that `decodeByteArray (...)` is actually meant to take an array of bytes that represents some standard image file format and decode it into a general purpose bitmap.

That being the case, would not something like:

```java
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap (w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Yes, ARGB
bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer (pixels);
```

make more sense?

I am not exactly sure what the JNI bindings are supposed to look like for this, but this creates a Bitmap from RAW pixel data rather than trying to decode something that isn't encoded in the first place. I imagine what you are trying to do fails almost immediately when Android cannot find a recognizable file signature in the first couple of bytes of data.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks mate. I will adjust the code accordingly